# bjam runtime-link=static

Tags: c++, boost, linker, bjam

I am trying to compile in a way such that the exec links to `gcc` statically. I presumed running `bjam link=static runtime-link=static` should do the trick ?
When I tried that I get the following errors like :

```
...failed gcc.link TGT/bin/gcc-4.5.1/debug/link-static/runtime-link-static/datagen...
gcc.compile.c++ TGT/bin/gcc-4.5.1/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/base_data_gen.o
gcc.link TGT/bin/gcc-4.5.1/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/datagen
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These don't come when I run `bjam link=static`.
Please advise ?

Comment: bjam isn't giving you the actual command that failed?  If you can run both with "bjam -d+2", you can compare the linker commands bjam is executing, and, from there, hopefully figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive that libstdc++ is intentionally not linked statically.  Doing so is considered by many to be filled with peril (though I have not really heard a good reason).  I do not think that there is a simple flag that you can add.  For the gcc toolset you would add something like

```
-static-libgcc  -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++
```

to your cxxflags for your  build variant.